# Binding DataGridComboBox to Enum

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm Currently Binding my Datagrid to a DTO. It's able to pull up values EXCEPT the enumeration. How Do I bind enumerations when the values coming in don't quite equal the enumeration.

```
public enum Channels { Phone, Website, Email, Skype, Cell, Fax }
```

But the possible values for `Channel` are Between 0-5

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding ContactMethods} >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn  
         Header="Type" 
         SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Channel, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         shell:EnumHelper.Enum="{x:Type clients:ContactMethods+Channels}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="Channel"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all values of an `enum` in XAML you can use an `ObjectDataProvider` like:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumDataProvider" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="NameSpaceOfMyEnum:MyEnum"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

To display the `enum`-values for example in a `ComboBox` (that's where I use this) you have to:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumDataProvider}}"
```

---

I've created a new Window and added an `ObjectDataProvider` in the Window.Resources. The xaml is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="250">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumDataProvider" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="wpfApplication1:MyEnum"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumDataProvider}}"></ComboBox>
</Window>
```

The `enum` is just

```
enum MyEnum
{
    EnumValue1,
    EnumValue2,
    EnumValue3,
}
```

I think your xaml from the comment works if you add

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

to your Namespaces of the window. The wpfApplication1 must by modified to match the namespace of your enum

Comment: I definitely Liked the approach you took, I'm having trouble trying to run it. I'm not sure where to put ObjectDataprovider, I put it inbetween window resources But i Get `Content can only be set once` `<usercontrol <window resources.... /> <Grid...../>/>

Comment: I defined the ObjectDataProvider in my App.xaml. If you post the complete xaml I can take a look at it

Comment: [Xaml](http://snag.gy/w3Q2q.jpg) if that helps. My next next problem is that the "prefix" of my namespace is not defined. [Namespace](http://snag.gy/g3L6O.jpg) I even attempted this: xmlns:clients="clr-namespace:Fern.FaaSBank.Models.Clients;assembly=Models" and the Namespace was clients:ContactMethods:Channels but that didn't work also

Comment: Using `xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:Fern.FaaSBank.Models.Clients;assembly=Models"` and `<x:Type TypeName="wpfApplication1:ContactMethod:Channel"></x:Type>` It still says "ContactMethod:Channel does not exist in the namespace

Comment: What's the name of your Project-File?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49504/discussion-between-tomtom-and-user3276954)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Channels { Phone, Website, Email, Skype, Cell, Fax }
var ChannelsForBind = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Channels)).Cast<Channels>();
```

Comment: Where Do I put ChannelsForBind? Channel is within a contactmethod class and I'm currently using MVVM